# How to focus program window instead of spawning new one if it's already open

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, gtk, dconf

I am currently using Linux Mint 19.03 Cinnamon.

## Issue

I launch `gnome-calculator` with <kbd>Cal</kbd> shortcut button and when I press that button, new `gnome-calculator` window is spawned. I don't want this behaviour.
[image]

## Expected result

I am expecting the <kbd>Cal</kbd> button launches `gnome-calculator` but if it is already running, when <kbd>Cal</kbd> is pressed again, it will reveal the existing window, and so on and so forth.

## Current attempt

I've found, using *dconf editor* that I can customize the desktop.
So far, I've also found the string to execute the `gnome-calculator` which is:

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.calculator exec 'gnome-calculator'
```

I use *dconf editor* such as this one:
[image]

So far, what I need is to change the **Custom value** with the proper command to check the existing calculator window and reveal it.

## The question

What is the command (or script too) to focus on existing `gnome-calculator` window? And if it doesn't exist, simply spawn one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not an expert and I have never had this thought, thus I never dig in it; anyway I would take a look at 1) `wmctrl` utility, and 2) GTK options.

Comment: @mattia.b89 thank you for wmctrl suggestion. I've posted an answer myself. please help to validate the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer. This problem turns out not a specific DE problem. It's the behavior of the app itself which is `gnome-calculator`.

I've found two methods(or workarounds) for doing this:

## Using *wmctrl*

So, the basic command is this:

```bsh
wmctrl -xa gnome-calculator || gnome-calculator
```

To make it work in *dconf* command, warp it in shell command and apply it to *dconf* using terminal such as this:

```bsh
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.calculator exec "sh -c 'wmctrl -xa gnome-calculator || gnome-calculator'"
```

## Using *xdotool*

With this one,you need to install`xdotool`.

The command:

```bsh
xdotool search --class gnome-calculator windowactivate || gnome-calculator
```

Dconf setting:

```bsh
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.calculator exec "sh -c 'xdotool search --class gnome-calculator windowactivate || gnome-calculator'"
```

**reference:**
[mattia-b89's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/186963/mattia-b89)
[askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269574/wmctrl-focus-most-recent-window-of-an-app)
[mtwebster's github comment](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/9281#issuecomment-622393193)

Comment: I appreciate this workaround, but I wonder if it's true that the problem is the behavior of the app itself. I've noticed all my "launch app" buttons have the same behavior (launch email, launch browser, launch settings, launch calculator, etc.). Whereas when I launch any of them from the GNOME shell, it does what I'd expect: it focuses on the existing window, if there is one.

Comment: @mmaluff its according to [this](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/9281#issuecomment-622393193) post, They leave the app to decide it's behavior.